# This end tag has no matching start tag. I messed up somewhere. Please look at it for me?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="StudentList" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstStudents" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="lstStudents_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:ListBox>
            <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Warning 4   This end tag has no matching start tag.
```

Is it that my tags are out of order? I am stumped.

Comment: Sometimes it takes Visual Studio a while until it checks for syntax again. In this case you see an error message although the error has already been fixed.

Comment: @kush - dtb is right on the money here.  I've seen this many times.  You have no tags out of order in the code you posted.

Comment: thanks guys. I restarted vs and the error isn't there anymore. Sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a doctype defined?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Just for the record, you can use [the great W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check the validity of HTML, XHTML and more.

Comment: Yes 

    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="StudentList.aspx.cs" Inherits="StudentListWeb.StudentList" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">